# Postgres: column "all_comments.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using `with recursive` to count the number of all descendants.
That would be the following SQL query, but if I specify only `root_id` for `group by`, I get
I get the following error.

`column "all_comments.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

I don't understand why this error occurs with `all_comments.id`.
Also, if I add `all_comments.id` to `group by`, this error does not occur, but
The original purpose of the `all_descendants.id` does not count well, and
rows of all descendants are returned.

I do not want to remove this column from the SELECT because we need to retrieve the id and other columns as well.

What can I do to resolve this?
Your help would be greatly appreciated.

```sql
with recursive all_comments as (
   select id, parent_id, id as root_id
   from videos_productvideocomment
   where parent_id is null
   union all
   select c.id, c.parent_id, p.root_id
   from videos_productvideocomment c
     join all_comments p on c.parent_id = p.id
)
select id, root_id, count(*) -1 as all_descendants_count
from all_comments
group by root_id;
```

Sample data and desired output

```
                Table "public.videos_productvideocomment"
    Column    |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 id           | uuid                     |           | not null |
 created_at   | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 updated_at   | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 text         | text                     |           | not null |
 commented_at | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 edited_at    | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 parent_id    | uuid                     |           |          |
 user_id      | uuid                     |           | not null |
 video_id     | uuid                     |           | not null |
```

```json
[
  {
    id: "uuid1",
    text: "...",
    reply_count: 10,
  },
  {
    id: "uuid5",
    text: "...",
    reply_count: 3,
  },
]
```

--- Edit --- Using the window function

```sql
with recursive all_comments as (
   select id, parent_id, id as root_id
   from videos_productvideocomment
   where parent_id is null
   union all
   select c.id, c.parent_id, p.root_id
   from videos_productvideocomment c
     join all_comments p on c.parent_id = p.id
)
select id, parent_id, root_id, count(root_id) OVER(PARTITION BY root_id) -1 as all_descendants_count
from all_comments
```

Results obtained

```json
[
  {
    id: "uuid1",
    parent_id: null,
    text: "...",
    reply_count: 10,
  },
  {
    id: "uuid5",
    parent_id: null,
    text: "...",
    reply_count: 3,
  },
  {
    id: "uuid8",
    parent_id: "uuid1",
    text: "...",
    reply_count: 0,
  },
  ...
]
```

We need to get only those with parent_id null, but if we add WHERE parent_id is null, all_descendants_count will be 0.

Comment: Remove Id from SELECT to make it a valid sql.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation.id and other columns must also be retrieved.

Comment: You can use the window `sum() over()` aggregate to keep all the rows and get totals column as well.

Comment: Sample data and the desired output would help.

Comment: Thank you. I have added this to the list, although it will be a simple one.

Comment: After a lot of testing, I was able to count all descendants without using GROUP BY by using the Window function (over()), but I do not need any rows except the most parent. However, if I use WHERE to select only rows that have no parent, the number of all descendants is displayed as 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a filter step after counting over the entire dataset, for example

```
with recursive all_comments as (
   select id, parent_id, id as root_id
   from videos_productvideocomment
   where parent_id is null
   union all
   select c.id, c.parent_id, p.root_id
   from videos_productvideocomment c
     join all_comments p on c.parent_id = p.id
)
select *
from (
    select id, parent_id, root_id, count(root_id) OVER(PARTITION BY root_id) -1 as all_descendants_count
    from all_comments
) t
where id = root_id
```